# Finding basis of a vector-subspace: Finding commuting matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I get to know a basis of a vector-subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ formed by matrices $X$ that commute with the matrix: $$A=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and compute the left and right products with $A$. This should give you restrictions on the coefficients in the matrix.

Say
$$X=\left[\begin{matrix}x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{matrix}\right] \; .$$

Then $XA=AX$ implies that $x_{21}=0$ and $x_{11}=x_{22}$. From this, it is straightforward to build a basis for the space of matrices $X$.

Answer (score 0):

**Inputs**
$$
  \mathbf{A} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right), \qquad
\mathbf{X} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0
 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**Multiplication**
$$
 \mathbf{AX} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & a \\
 0 & c \\
\end{array}
\right), \qquad
 \mathbf{XA} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & d \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\tag{1}
$$

**Conditions**

Under what conditions does
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{AX} &= \mathbf{XA} ?\\
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & a \\
 0 & c \\
\end{array}
\right) &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & d \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
$$

Conditions to satisfy $(1)$:

1. $a=d$
2. $c=0$
3. $b\in\mathbb{C}$